minimization: number of coordinates in coordinate file does not match topology
I am trying to make a CG membrane using Insane with python3.
To make the membrane, I downloaded all the required files and installed insane.
Then I modified the lipids.dat file to add the coordinates of my own lipid that I wanted my membrane to have.
to get the coordinates, I used CHARMM-GUI to first get the atomic coordinates of a pdb file.
Then I used cg builder to get the coordinates of the CG format (I mapped the atomic into CG).
I used the x, y, and z coordinates in the lipids.dat file (which I pasted below).
Then I tried to neutralize and minimize my system which gave me an error before I could run the minimization (The title)
I checked and counted all of the CG beads and the numbers match in the topology and the gro files and they match. Where would the problem be from?
[LIPA]
0  -0.7   0.2   0.2   0.1   0.2  -0.1  -0.8  -1  -1  -1.2   0  -0.3  -0.2  -0.1  -0.2  0  0   0.2   0  -0.3   0.3   0.4   1   1.1   1.1   1.4  -0.4  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5  -0.3   0.4   0.5   0.9
2.2  -0.4   1.5   1.4   0.9   1.5   1.9   1.9   1.4   0.8  -0.3   0.6  -0.2  -0.3  -0.3  -0.4   0.1   0.1   0.2   0.1  -0.2  -0.1  -0.3  -0.3  -0.1   0.1   0.2  -0.4  -0.7  -0.7  -0.8  -0.9   0.5   0.6   0.6
3.5   4.0   3.8   3.5   3.6   3.2   2.9   2.7   2.5   2.2   2.2   3.3   3.2   3.0   2.6   2.1   2.9   2.4   2.0   3.7   3.7   3.7   3.5   3.3   3.1   2.7   2.3   3.6   3.5   3.1   2.7   2.4   2.8   2.3   1.9
;     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30    31    32     33    34    35
LIPA    PO2   PO1   GM2   GM3   GM1   GM4   CCD   C1D   C2D   C3D   C4D   GM5   CAB   C1B   C2B   C3B   C1A   C2A   C3A   ZM1   ZM2   ZM3   ZM4    CE   C1E   C2E   C3E   ZM5    CF   C1F   C2F
I am assuming the problem is coming from these coordinates but not sure how to fix it? (from lipids.dat)
The command to make the membrane (I have used this command before and it worked perfectly for minimization):
insane -o Ecoli-LIPA-AMP.gro -p Ecoli-LIPA-AMP.top -d 0 -x 25 -y 25 -z 10 -u LIPA:100 -l OPMN:1 -l OPMV:1 -l MPPV:2 -l MPPM:1 -l PMPG:7 -l PNPG:2 -l OVPG:1 -l PVPG:3 -l POPG:2 -l MOPG:0 -l PMPE:17 -l OVPE:16 -l PNPE:6 -l MVPE:13 -l PVPE:28 -l MOPE:0 -l NVPE:0 -l DVPE:0 -l DPPE:0 -au 1.6 -sol W -salt 0.15 -center -orient
I'm very new to this field.  would appreciate any help, papers, or anything I could read that would help me gain more.
I tried re-scaling and renaming the beads

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
